# value of $\det(P^2+Q^2)$

Tags: determinant

> If $P$ and $Q$  be $3\times 3$ matrices and $P\neq Q. $
>
> If $P^3=Q^3$ and $P^2Q=Q^2P.$ Then  $\det(P^2+Q^2)$ is

Try: From

$P^3-Q^3=O\Rightarrow (P-Q)(P^2+PQ+Q^2)=O$

So either $P=Q$ or either $P^2+PQ+Q^2=O$

So $P^2+Q^2=-PQ$, Now i did not understand how

i use $P^2Q=Q^2P$ and find $\det(P^2+Q^2)$

Could some help me how to find it, thanks

Comment: Hint: $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$

Comment: @Stockfish how i find $\det(P)\det(Q)$ from $P^2Q=Q^2P$

Comment: consider $\det(P^2Q) = \det(Q^2P)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

- Establish the equality $\left(P^2+Q^2\right)\left(P-Q\right)=0$.
- Using $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, we derive that either $\det\left(P^2+Q^2\right)=0$ or $\det\left(P-Q\right)=0$.
- Suppose that $\det\left(P^2+Q^2\right)\neq 0$. Then $P^2+Q^2$ is invertible: left-multiply by $\left(P^2+Q^2\right)^{-1}$ in equality  $\left(P^2+Q^2\right)\left(P-Q\right)=0$ to reach a contradiction.

Comment: You don't need the second bullet point.